# Teste automatizado para verificar uma confirmação de email

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados

Estou criando testes automatizados com o selenium webdriver. Preciso fazer um teste que verifique se um email é enviado ao usuário após o seu cadastro no sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bom voce tem que fazer o selenium enviar o email pelo sistema, dai voce cria uma classe  que abra um navegador e entre na url do email cadastrado coloque login e senha  acesse a caixa de entrada dai este email é deve ir com um titulo padarao voce colocar o selenium para clicar no email com xpath exemplo //div [text()='titulo do email'] dai ele clica verifica o conteudo e depois voce exlui o email para que da proxima vez que execultar nao tenha problemas. se quiser ajuda em como montar o codigo posta aqui o problema que respondo com maior prazer.